# Pushing an associative array into another in PHP

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am new to PHP and JSON, and I am attempting to be able to add attributes to json files at runtime using php.

For example, the json currently looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"john"
    },
    {
        "name": "james"
    }
]
```

I then want to be able to (using php), refer to the file and alter it as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name":"john",
        "Round1Prediction":"7"
    },
    {
        "name": "james"
    }
]
```

At the moment, when I get the contents of the json:
`$jsonPlayers = json_decode($strJsonFileContents, true);
var_dump($jsonPlayers); // print array`

The output is as follows:

```
array(4) 
{
  [0]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(1) "q"
                }
  [1]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(1) "w"
                }
  [2]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(1) "e"
                }
  [3]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(2) "rt"
                }
}
```

To visualise what i would like to do (by typing it manually):
array(4)

```
{
  [0]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(1) "q"
                    ["Round1Prediction"]=>string(1) "5"
                }
  [1]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(1) "w"
                }
  [2]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(1) "e"
                }
  [3]=> array(1){
                    ["name"]=>string(2) "rt"
                }
}
```

So how would i go about pushing the extra item in? I have tried this...:

```
$input = array($attrName => $value);
$newjsonPlayers = array_push($jsonPlayers[0], $input);
```

...and a couple other unsuccessful attempts. Can anyone help? I really tried to format this question so that it was easier to understand, but can try and explain more if necessary.

tldr im trying to push an associative array into another, how can i go about doing so? Is there any alternative ways? Is it even possbile?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You should be able to set it directly rather than push the value in - try `$jsonPlayers[0][$attrName] = $value;`

Comment: @NigelRen perfect thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set it directly rather than push the value in - try

```
$jsonPlayers[0][$attrName] = $value;
```